# How to determine when SIP (software keyboard) is dismissed in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How to determine when SIP (software input panel) is dismissed in Windows Phone 8?

Searched on StackOverflow and online but found nothing!

Answer (score 3):

The keyboard is dismissed when no textbox has a focus, so you can use that as an indicator.

What I think was impossible in WP7 (not sure whether it has changed in WP8) was to detect whether the SIP keyboard vs. hardware keyboard was used. But then again, how many WP8 phones have hardware keyboards? :)

Comment: That is not an ideal solution. Should not have to check each textbox on the page for focus! I am trying to find either an API (possibly), something like Keyboard.IsOpen, or an event that is generated when keyboard is deployed or dismissed, something like keyboard_dismissed(KeyboardEventArgs).

Comment: Why downvote?! I didn't say it was ideal. But there isn't an API to my knowledge. If you want to waste time looking for an API, be my guest.

Comment: What you said was not the answer to the question. The question asked how determine "when" the SIP is dismissed, not to check each text box to see if it has focus or not and then infer that the SIP is down!

Comment: That's **how** one can determine when it's dismissed. Obviously, it's not ideal, but there is no other magical way. That doesn't make my answer incorrect. But whatever... I'm _glad_ I decided to spend some time reading your question and trying to help.

Comment: Please allow me to clarify what the question was asking (I'll try and make the question a little more clearer if I still can): What I was trying to ask is to somehow capture the event when the keyboard is dismissed or to get an auto-notification of such an event, not to actually know if the keyboard is dismissed at a given point in time or not - you see the difference? PS: I tried up-voting on your answer to negate the down-vote, given that there could have been a confusion caused, but you will need to edit your answer for me to be able to do that!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there is no API, or an event generated to know when the keyboard is dismissed.